# Reference request: Morita contexts

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory

During an independent study I've come across Morita contexts, but I'd like to understand them better. A quick Google search doesn't yield much fruit, so I was hoping to find a good reference on the topic, preferably dealing with some of the more basic properties so I can get a feel for how to work with them

Thanks!

References I have: Rowen's *Graduate Algebra: Noncommutative View* and McConnell and Robson's *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings*. Neither spend too much time on the topic (in fact, the material on Morita contexts is in an appendix in Rowen's text).

Comment: It would help if you mention the reference you did find.

Comment: Whoops! They have been added

Comment: There is something in Rowen's "Ring Theory - Volume I". The beginning of chapter 4 deals with Morita contexts and the Morita theorems. Chapter 8 of Lam's "Lectures on modules and rings" (GTM 189) also deals with Morita stuff.

Comment: Thanks Has, I'll be looking at them both today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely second Has Giebenrath's recommendation of Lam's coverage in *Lectures on modules and rings*, and I would add Anderson and Fuller's coverage in *Rings and categories of modules*.

While I haven't had time to read it, I imagine [Wisbauer's book](http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/book.pdf) also has good coverage on the topic.

Comment: I appreciate it!